# Combinatorics: Ramsey Theory Problem

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

**Colour the integers 1,2,...,1978 with 6 colours. Prove that there are three integers x,y,z in the set that are of the same colour, and x+y=z.**

I have just joined this site, I'm informed in combinatorics, and have just started looking into Ramsey Theory. In my research I found this problem, and would be curious to see what approaches anyone would have for the proof.

I would like to give more context, although I was told this question verbally from an acquaintance when asking for problems in Ramsey Theory and I can't seem to find it anywhere on the internet.

---

Any thoughts or solutions would be exceedingly helpful, or if anyone could recognize the problem or it's source.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Questions like this, which are really requests for discussion, should be asked in chat.  Here on the main site the question should be clear, focused, show the work you've already attempted and the thoughts you've had (to help answerers provide useful answers!).  Improving your question will much improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: I've only just joined the site, and got a satisfactory answer as well. The question was how one could approach this proof using Ramsey Theory, the answer explained it, it's hardly a request for discussion (then again, I suppose any question is to a certain degree). I'll definitely try to show my progress on further posts (even if I've made none). I've got the answer now, so I can delete this post if it is such a travesty for others to gaze upon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is IMO 1978/6. A solution is provided here: [https://www.math.cmu.edu/~ploh/docs/math/mop2009/combin-gems.pdf](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Eploh/docs/math/mop2009/combin-gems.pdf) (page 4). 
A summary:
1978 is larger than the 6-color Ramsey number for triangles. Let $G$ be a complete graph with vertex set ${0, 1, ..., 1978}$, and color the edge $ij$ with the color of $|i-j|$. Then there exists a monochromatic triangle, so some $|i-j|, |j-k|, |k-i|$ all have the same color. Two of those must sum to the third.

Comment: It is strange I could not find this document, however. I checked the IMO database and indeed it appears that this problem I was told is a slight variation of the 1978 IMO Problem 6, very likely from the document "Combinatorial Gems" by Po-Shen Loh which you have linked. Strangely, this variation is almost of an identical structure but with a different analogy. Regardless, thank you very much for finding it and providing a summary which was exactly what I was looking for.